# Is it possible to use `%Regex.Matcher` in a SQL Query via ODBC?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have to get a list of codes that match a pattern from a Caché DB. I do not have access to the server to run commands directly and can only access the data via an ODBC connection. Is there a way to make use of the `%Regex.Matcher` method in a SQL Query?

I know that `%Pattern` can be used in a SQL query, but I'd rather use standard regular expressions rather than having to use Caché ObjectScript pattern codes.

I've tried `SELECT * FROM TBL.CODES WHERE CODE %REGEX.MATCHER "[O][0-9]{2}"` and `SELECT * FROM TBL.CODES WHERE %REGEX.MATCHER("[O][0-9]{2}", CODE)` with no success.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-use-regex-regular-expression-sql-statement And you can also call 'CREATE PROCEDURE' via ODBC

Comment: Would I be able to do that with read permissions?

Comment: You'll need %CREATE_PROCEDURE permission